# how to disable wireless card with powershell?

Tags: powershell, networking, wifi

I need to completly shutdown the Wireless card of a laptop via powershell (with PS 3 and Win 7), when a lan cable is plugged.

I'm trying with Win32_NetworkAdapter class and Disable method.

```
get-wmiobject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter | Where-Object {$_.DeviceId -eq 7} | foreach {$_.Disable()}
```

I should have '0' as returnvalue (success) but I get '5', which corresponds to a mismatch error... I don't understand why. I've tried also with

```
$nic = get-wmiobject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "DeviceId = 7"
$nic.Disable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this [LINK](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/01/13/enabling-and-disabling-network-adapters-with-powershell/). Hope its help.